# Product images not visible in backend product edit (Magento 1.9.1.0)

Tags: product-images, backend, prototype-js

After installing SUPEE 8788, images are not visible in Product Edit section of backend. They are visible in product-grid and in frontend also.
[image: Backend]

[image: Console]

Comment: Please remove cache. Logout and login again and then check.

Comment: @Kul - it didn't work

Comment: пиздец блять комьюнити